# Get a round border for tooltip by using clip-path

Tags: html, css, tooltip, linear-gradients, clip-path

Having a really annoying CSS challenge I need to make the tooltip has linear gradient background also have a round border around it.

Here is my workaround but only the top two corners have a round border since I used `clip-path`, is there any way to make the bottom two corners have `border-radius` as well?  (no pseudo-class please)

[image]

thanks heaps

```css
.wrapper, .container {
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% calc(100% - 10px), calc(50% + 10px) calc(100% - 10px), 50% 100%, calc(50% - 10px) calc(100% - 10px), 0% calc(100% - 10px));
}


.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.container {
  padding: 8px 8px 17px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #000 39%, transparent 39%, transparent 61%, black 61%) no-repeat, linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.8) 0%, blue 100%);
  background-size: 100% 1px, 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Content</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Polygons do not have curves. Use a clip path instead.